# Group by in linq and show group items that all have the same value of a property

Tags: c#, linq

```
var sameItems = items
    .Where(x => x.Group != null)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Group)
    .Select(x => x.ToList())
    .Where(x => x.All(y=> y.Status == 1)); // Not working :(

Item Group Status 
Item1 1 1
Item2 1 2
Item3 1 1
Item4 2 1
Item5 2 1
```

So I would like to return items 4 and 5.
First I want to group by group number, and return items only those that have the same status of 1 and belong to the same group. Items 1, 2, and 3 belong to the same group, but not all have the status 1, so I want to exclude them.

Comment: What does not work to you?

Comment: It returns all The items with the status 1 regardless of my condition.

Comment: Can you add a full reproducer, case i [can't](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iwdTFi) reproduce it ?

Comment: Seems like your code is working as you want: https://pastebin.com/uKz3P1FR

Comment: FYI, `GroupBy` skips `null` keys, `Where(x => x.Group != null)` seems to be redundant

Answer (score 1):

Check the example here, it might help you:
[dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LjMrry)

It seems to work as you expected, you might need to dismantle the group hierarchy if you just want to use them as a list.

```
var sameItems = items
    .Where(x => x.Group != null)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Group)
    .Select(x => x.ToList())
    .Where(x => x.All(y => y.Status == 1))
    .SelectMany(x => x);

foreach (var sameItem in sameItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sameItem.Item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

I have tested your code, if your items really have the values you say they have (Would be great to see) then the LINQ query gives you an array with items 4 and 5, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: This should be a comment, please read [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). (Yes, i am aware, that you are missing some points to be able to comment)

Comment: @NetMage Well, earn some points via questions or (actual) answers. With 19k points a assume you are: firstly aware of this rule and secondly you want to mock me :p SO makes those rules. And btw. i did not downvote, i just informed - with a link, that explains what can be done.

Comment: @nilsK No, I think your comment was unhelpful because it links to something irrelevant to your comment. If the response should be a comment and requires more points to make, then you are essentially saying the input isn't valued here. Which doesn't seem deserved.

Comment: I linked the SO tutorial/explanation page. On that page is an explanation on "how to write a good answer". That should help to improve a question. So, are you missing the "how to comment" tutorial? I really dont get your point and ... why is this so important? New user answers, got a hint on how to improve, done. Why are we still talking? (not meant to be rude)